# Grabbing a part of the screen as an image

Tags: applications, pdf, screenshots

I am reading a pdf file and I need to select a specific area in the file and paste it into my note in Papyrus. How to grab a specific area in a pdf file? Pdf reader iannotate does not allow me to do that. Is there a customizable screenshot command or some other app? This is w.r.t. Samsung Note 10.1.

Comment: Why do you need a customizable screenshot? Just take a normal screenshot and then crop it with the built-in photo editor.

Comment: That's double work for me and I have to do this for many images.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Screenshot Ultimate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.screenshotultimate).

What I would do is enable the Folder Listener trigger, and make sure the settings points to the correct screenshot folder. After this is enabled, I'd take a screenshot normally. Then, the app will ask me what to do with it. I'd click Edit, and Crop it.